# How to get LTSB revision number from ISO

Tags: windows

There are monthly (give or take) revisions to the various Windows 10 Builds, for example, LTSB 1607 has almost two dozen Build Numbers corresponding to KBs and release dates, such as 14393.1198 (released 5/9/2017) or 14393.693 (released 1/10/2017). We've found a spot where these specific builds are noted in the registry of an installed and running Win10/LTSB1607 machine.

But, is there a way to find that build number (specifically the number after 14393) on the ISO downloaded from Microsoft?

We've got a couple of the ISOs floating around, and we'd like to know if we can determine which ones are which. We can't just use the date of the files, and most the data on finding "language/edition/build/architecture" ends at "14393". We're interested in using the most recent ISO build because bandwidth at satellite locations is *extremely* limited, and downloading multiple Windows updates after installation of an older ISO is a problem. So we would like to get the current revisions out to each of those sites, but we're not sure how to ensure what revisions are already there.

Would we just be better off using whatever revision we have and creating a custom patched/updated installer? Would a current revision be smaller and faster than using that revision and slipstreaming updates (or using MDT)?

Comment: I haven't been able to locate anything that would lead me to an answer for this so far. Hard to find suggestions other than using "Get-WindowsImage...." This doesn't help us with the revision number after the build number, though. Still looking.

Answer (score 1):

Mount the ISO, and use the Get-WindowsImage powershell command against the install.wim.  The **Version** should be what you want.

```
PS C:\users> Get-WindowsImage -ImagePath h:\sources\install.wim -Index 1

ImageIndex       : 1
ImageName        : Windows 10 Enterprise
ImageDescription : Windows 10 Enterprise
ImageSize        : 15,292,901,009 bytes
WIMBoot          : False
Architecture     : x64
Hal              :
Version          : 10.0.15063.0
SPBuild          : 0
SPLevel          : 0
EditionId        : Enterprise
InstallationType : Client
ProductType      : WinNT
ProductSuite     : Terminal Server
SystemRoot       : WINDOWS
DirectoryCount   : 19668
FileCount        : 101858
CreatedTime      : 3/18/2017 7:58:23 PM
ModifiedTime     : 3/18/2017 8:26:40 PM
Languages        : en-US (Default)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. We want the revision with the number after the 15063 build, for example, 15063.296 or 15063.138. That would tell us which revision we're dealing with and the age of our ISO, I think.