# Do LTSB ISOs on VLSC get updated with new revisions?

Tags: windows-10

I posted the question on "[How to get LTSB revision number from ISO](https://serverfault.com/questions/855372/how-to-get-ltsb-revision-number-from-iso)", but I'm starting to wonder if there even are new ISOs released as updates/patches(/New KB) are released. TechNet shows that there are builds released fairly regularly with corresponding KB articles ([this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-info.aspx) shows an OS Build of 14393.1358 with a release date of 6/13/2017).

Does that mean a new ISO should be available in the VLSC?

Does anyone know if there's recent LTSB 1607 available, or just one from last year? Do different vendors have different access/files for something like LTSB 1607 builds?

If not, I'll close the other question as answered as well, I reckon.